# シェルスクリプトのfor文で配列変数を使いたい。

Tags: bash, shellscript, sh

配列変数をfor文に渡して、配列要素にアクセスしたいのですが、うまくいきません。
このようなアクセスはできないのでしょうか？

```
list1=(aa bb)
list2=(cc dd)

for l in list1 list2
do
  echo $l[0];
  echo $l[1];
done
```

**実行結果**

```
list1[0]
list1[1]
list2[0]
list2[1]
```

**期待する結果**

```
aa
bb
cc
dd
```

Comment: 「このようなアクセス」とは「間接参照」のことでした。

Comment: evalを使えばよいという回答をいただき、下記のようにして
解決することができました。ありがとうございました。

    list1=(aa bb)
    list2=(cc dd)

    for l in list1 list2
    do
        eval echo \${$l[0]};
        eval echo \${$l[1]};
    done

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「このようなアクセス」というのが `indirect reference`(間接参照)を意味するのであれば、bash でもできなくはないです。

```
list1=(aa bb)
list2=('cc      123' -n)

for l in list1 list2
do
  eval printf '%s\\n' \"\${$l[1]}\"
  eval printf '%s\\n' \"\${$l[0]}\"
done
```

`eval` を使うので `\\n` や `\"` としています。また、`echo` ではなく `printf` を使っているのは配列の要素に `-n` や `-e` がある場合を考慮しているためです(`echo` のオプションとして処理されてしまいます)。

Answer (score 4):

bashのfor文は`in`の後に記述されたものを順番に実行します。そのため、`l`に入れる要素が`in`のあとに順番に並んでいる必要があります。

```
for l in "${list1[@]}" "${list2[@]}"
do
  echo $l
done
```

Answer (score 4):

シェル、bashの文法に関し、二つほど勘違いがあると思いますので、補足しておきます。

#### 変数の参照

シェルにおいては殆どの場所で、変数名を書いても、それはだだ文字列としか見なされません。

```
list1=(aa bb)
list2=(cc dd)

echo list1 list2
# list1 list2 はただの文字列
# 出力は 'list1 list2'
```

これは`for`文の`in`の後もそうです。
`for l in list1 list2;` とした時`l`は代入する変数名として扱われますが、`list1 list2`はただの文字列です。
`l`という変数には`list1`と`list2`という文字列が順番に代入されます。
`echo "$l"` としても、この文字列が出力されることになりますから`list1`などと表示されるだけです。

ですから、変数`l`に代入する前の段階で、変数`list1`と`list2`の値を参照し展開しておこう、というのがemasakaさんの回答です。
出力する段階で、`l`に代入されている文字列を変数名として解釈させて、それの値を取り出そう、というのがargusさんの回答です。

#### 配列変数の要素の参照

bashで配列の要素を参照するには `${list[0]}`のように`{}`で囲まなければいけません。
シェルでは`[]`をパス名展開に使用するので、それと区別するためこれが必要になっています。

```
list=(aa bb)

echo $list[0]
# $list は list の最初の要素（この場合 'aa'）に展開される。
# それに '[0]' が付き、'aa[0]' になる。
# この 'aa[0]' に対し、パス名展開が行なわれ、
# 'aa'の後に'0'が有るファイル名に対しマッチが試みられる。
# よって、出力は 'aa0' という名前のファイルが有れば、'aa0' 無ければ 'aa[0]'。

echo "$list[0]"
# ""でクオートされている
# この場合 'aa[0]' になる所までは一緒だがパス名展開はされない。
# 出力は 'aa[0]'。

echo "${list[0]}"
# {}を付けているので配列の要素への参照になる。
# 出力は 'aa'。
```

Answer (score 3):

間接参照とすると、bashには間接参照として`${!var}`という方法があるのですが、`${!var[1]}`のようには使えないみたいですね。

というわけで、やや冗長ですが。

```
list1=(aa bb)
list2=(cc dd)

for l in list1 list2
do
  x=$l[0]
  echo ${!x}
  x=$l[1]
  echo ${!x}
done
```

あるいは、bash 4.3以降であれば、namerefを使って。

```
list1=(aa bb)
list2=(cc dd)

for l in list1 list2
do
  declare -n x=$l
  echo ${x[0]}
  echo ${x[1]}
done
```